# Error loading component com.cck on joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Whenever i try to add an article from frontend i get the error as written in the subject. I login as author, Textfilters are set to no filtering.
I have also tried to log in as admin - same error. 
I receive a message and the article is there but it is not that pretty to have an error message when trying to add articles.
Joomla version 2.5.4 - all should be updated. 
What could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Seblod function if you are not using Seblod CCK Component.

Find file: modules\mod_news_pro_gk4\gk_classes\gk_utils.php
Find & Remove Lines 17 to 27 which is below.

```
  // 
  $cck_path = JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_cck';
  if (file_exists($cck_path)) {
     if(JComponentHelper::isEnabled('com_cck', true)){
        // Force parsing plugin if SEBLOD is used
        if($this->config['parse_plugins'] == FALSE) {
            $text = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $text);
        }
        $text = trim(substr(strip_tags( $text,"<br /><br><strong></strong><p></p><i></i><b></b><span></span><ul></ul><li></li><blockquote></blockquote>"),0));
     }
  }
```